# File not found error from the listbox C# win forms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a listbox and it has some files loaded from a directory folder.

Code to load the files into the listBox1:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PopulateListBox(listbox1, @"C:\TestLoadFiles", "*.rtld");

        }

private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }
```

I want to read and display the attributes values to the labels in the form. The loaded files in the `listBox1`, here is the code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string path = (string)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    DisplayFile(path);
} 
private void DisplayFile(string path)
{
    string xmldoc = File.ReadAllText(path);

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmldoc))
    {   

        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
        {
          switch (reader.Name)
          {
            case "description":
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value))
                label5.Text = reader.Value; // your label name
              break;
            case "sourceId":
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reader.Value))
                label6.Text = reader.Value; // your label name
              break;
            // ... continue for each label
           }
        }
    }
}
```

`Problem:`When I click on the file in the listBox1 after the form is loaded,the files are loaded from the folder into the listbox but it's throwing an error `File not found in the directory`.

How can I fix this problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are adding `File.Name` instead you should add `File.FullName` in your listbox

```
lsb.Items.Add(file.FullName);
```

so your method PopulateListBox should become:

```
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
            FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                lsb.Items.Add(file.FullName);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**
It looks like you want to display only the file name, not the full path. You could follow a following approach. In PopulateListBox, add `file`  instead of file.FullName so the line should be

```
foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                lsb.Items.Add(file);
            }
```

Then in SelectedIndexChanged event do the following:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileInfo file = (FileInfo)listbox1.SelectedItem;
            DisplayFile(file.FullName);
         }
```

This should get you the full name (file name with path) and will resolve your exception of File Not Found

Comment: @KarthikRANGARAJ, I didn't get you, do you want to show the name only  and then get full Name to display file ?

Comment: In the listBox1, I have to show just the `file names` from the folder and when I click on it then it should read the attribute values of the corresponding file into the labels.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I have an another problem here,  i'm getting error in this line as `illegal characters in path` at `using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmldoc))` can you help me with this.

Comment: @KarthikRANGARAJ, there is probably something wrong with the XML , you may post a new question with your XML or try to see what if you can debug it

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that in the listbox you only specify the file name, and not the entire file path and name, so when it looks for the file you it cant find it.

From [FileInfo.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx)

```
Gets the name of the file.
```

Whereas [File.ReadAllText Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx) takes `path` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the full path.

Try something like this:

```
 DisplayFile(@"C:\TestLoadFiles\" + path)
```

Comment: I used your method but i'm getting error in this line as `illegal characters in path` at  `using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmldoc))`